# How to add dynamic google maps to my mobile app

Tags: maps

I'm building a HTML5 & phonegap based mobile app for a city. I want when user click "restaurants" button it automatically shows the list of restaurants and map ,  same with hotels too .

any solutions for that

Comment: Please clarify you question/task and provide some code/info about what you have tried already.

Comment: @cmmi i have made a button 

<input type="button" name="button" value="Restaurants">

I want if a user (my mobile app user) clicks this button then a map opens listing all Restaurants on it. Like we search on google or like google places app

Comment: so you basically want to issue a query against Google Maps? So start with building this link.